# Problems changing the address of a pointer in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

In the code exerpt below, it gives me **warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type** for both of the lines noted. what am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct {
    char* string;
    struct samplelist* nextchunk;
    struct samplelist* prevchunk;
} samplelist;

samplelist* startsamplelist;
samplelist* lastsamplelist;


samplelist* newchunk = checked_malloc(sizeof(samplelist));

lastsamplelist->nextchunk = newchunk; //warning here
newchunk->prevchunk = lastsamplelist; // warning here
lastsamplelist = newchunk; //no problem here though
```

edit: attached the relevant definitions, answer below did not rely on code added. was syntax error

Comment: post `checked_malloc` code

Comment: why don't you do: `newchunk = (samplelist*) malloc(sizeof(samplelist));`

Comment: It's a library that I've been told to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the problem: you need to also add the symbol `samplelist` on the first line after `struct`

```
typedef struct samplelist {
    char* string;
    struct samplelist* nextchunk;
    struct samplelist* prevchunk;
} samplelist;
```

in general, it could be:

```
typedef struct foobar {
    char* string;
    struct foobar* nextchunk;
    struct foobar* prevchunk;
} samplelist;
```

ps: i personally think `typedef`s suck and are best used very sparingly

Comment: This a snippit from a large piece of code. Let's just pretend that **startsamplelist** and **lastsamplelist** are initialized the same way **newchunk** is.